# Specify distance between listview items

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Is there a way to remove destance between listview items?

If yes please tell me the way

I want to creat a custom listview and remove space between items like this below image.

Item 1 goes into item 2 and so on...

Example

[HUD design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQciR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set some tag in your list view like this:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
  android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>
```

or set this one by programmatically

```
listView().setDividerHeight(10)
```